# Converting array of flat data to nested object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Where filter1Prop is always the same value for a corresponding filter1ID, and filter2Prop is always the same value for a corresponding filter2ID,

I have an array of objects with the following structure:

```
[{
    filter1ID: 'FLTR1ID1',
    filter1Prop: 'Property 1',
    filter2ID: 'FLTR2ID1',
    filter2Prop: 'Property 2',
},
{
    filter1ID: 'FLTR1ID1',
    filter1Prop: 'Property 1',
    filter2ID: 'FLTR2ID2',
    filter2Prop: 'Property 3',
}]
```

This needs to be transformed to give an array of objects with the following structure (duplicate properties are combined):

```
[{
    id: 'FLTR1ID1',
    prop: 'Property 1',
    filter2: [
        {
            id: 'FLTR2ID1',
            prop: 'Property 2',
        },
        {
            id: 'FLTR2ID2',
            prop: 'Property 3',
        },
    ],
}]
```

I have achieved this by using Array.prototype.reduce(), followed by a map on the output object values as follows:

```js
const rowsToObject = rows => Object.values(rows.reduce((map, obj) => {
    map[obj.filter1ID] = map[obj.filter1ID] || {
        id: '',
        prop: '',
        filter2: {},
    };
    const filter1 = map[obj.filter1ID];

    filter1.id = obj.filter1ID;
    filter1.prop = obj.filter1Prop;
    filter1.filter2[obj.filter2ID] = filter1.filter2[obj.filter2ID] || {
        id: '',
        prop: '',
    };
    const filter2 = filter1.filter2[obj.filter2ID];

    filter2.id = obj.filter2ID;
    filter2.prop = obj.filter2Prop;

    return map;
}, Object.create(null))).map(result => ({
    ...result,
    filter2: Object.values(result.filter2),
}));
```

I would like it if I could process each entry from the input array just once.

Is there a way to avoid the use of Array.prototype.map() at the end without having to do find operations on the filter2 array?

Comment: Looking just at the two structures, this should be as simple as: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/4fyubcpd/ am I missing something?

Comment: You are totally right. I think I removed too much information from the problem. I will update my question. Thanks @ChrisG

Comment: I think you do not need to maintain an inner map for filter2 if the values in filter2 will be unique

Comment: Can there be duplicates of `filter2ID` for a single `filter1ID`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the values in filter2 can have duplicates. I've updated the question to include that. Thanks @ShubhamKhatri